# Google "One Tap" Verification: Wrong number of segments in token

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-authentication

In the HTML in the site I have got from the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap)

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>

      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id={googleClientID}
        data-login_uri='https://mytestdomain.appspot.com/google'
        data-return_uri={uri}
      ></div>
```

When the site loads it shows me the prompt to continue with my google account, I click continue and it shows me as logged in, the webhook does get called and I can get the `g_csrf_token` from the cookie, then I try to verify it using the `google-auth-library` as described [here in the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token) which is linked from the [one-tap docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
...
app.post("/google", function(req, res) {
  const idToken = req.cookies.g_csrf_token;
  const audience = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
  const client = new OAuth2Client(audience);
  async function verify() {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken, audience });
    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
    const userid = payload["sub"];
    console.log('------------------ userid');
    console.log(userid);
  }
  verify().catch(console.error);
  res.status(200).send({ req });
});
```

Th error I get is

```
Error: Wrong number of segments in token: 87ba1eb4d6261b6b      at OAuth2Client.verifySignedJwtWithCertsAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:525:19)      at OAuth2Client.verifyIdTokenAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:391:34)      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)      at async verify (/app/server.js:71:20)
```

The docs do suggest that we should get the token as a POST parameter as well as in the cookie, I have checked `req.body.credential`, `req.query.credential`, `req.params.credential` but there is no token to be found, from the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)

`After an ID token is returned from Google, it's submitted by an HTTP POST method request to your login endpoint with the parameter name credential.`

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? i've hit the same block

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out - we were both using the `g_csrf_token` cookie for the idToken but that's wrong!

You basically need to get the `request.body.credential` (or `req.body.credential` in your case) instead, which is a JWT. Then it should work!

Comment: Please can u show us how you implement it in your code, this answer confuses me